# unwrap long bendy looped plane

Tags: texturing, uv, faces, unity

Hey i've been at this for a bit trying to find an efficient way to do it but i figured I'd ask here just in case someone has a better way to do it.
Just for context, I'm making a small environment for a game, just a simple little forest, and I'm making the borders planes that are extruded and looped around the environment that I'm trying to apply a looping texture to, that texture just being a few trees with transparency at the top. My issue is i've been trying to unwrap it so that, I guess just like all of the faces unwrap into a single square, so that I can loop the texture without worrying about having to rotate it or have like one face be right and the rest super stretched.
is there a way to do this that doesn't involve selecting, unwrapping, and rotating each individual face?
Edit: here's a screenshot of a good portion of the mesh, and the texture i'm trying to use-
[image]

[image]

Comment: An illustration of the loop of planes would really help, here?